# How to Hide/Show listview on Alternative Touches

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview. Now i need to hide/ display the listview. Listview is at left corner of my screen and now what i want is when i touch the left corner of my layout my listview should hide and when i touch again it should display,simply hide/show listview on alternative touch events.And this is similar like hiding seek bar in media player at the time of playing video.I can show/hide it in layout but i want listview to show and hide exactly when i touches the left corner of the screen. I tried with on touch listener and others, but i need this to happen when i touch the corner of screen.As am a newbie, help me in achieving this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

easy way to achieve is

1) put a button on your corner where you want to(make button transparent if you dont want to make it visible).

2) set click listener on that button.

eg.

```
Button corner;
corner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(lstview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                    lstview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    lstview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already i tried this way and it's working fine. But i want the view to hide/display exactly when i go near the left corner of the view

Comment: And if i place a button only when i click the button the view become visible/in visible. But from starting to ending of left corner where ever i touch i need the view to get hide and display.

Answer (score 0):

object.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or show mateobject.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0):

i think the esyest solution (not the most elegant) for you is to put a trasparent view in the left corner of your layout (above the other) and set a click listener on it.

the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/invisible_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the `OnClickListener`:

```
OnClickListener onClickHide = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(listView.isShown()) {
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }           
    }       
};
```